# How to fetch active posts from database

Tags: php, sql

Here is my index page code. I already used where clause but throwing some errors

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT
    tblposts.id AS pid,
    tblposts.PostTitle AS posttitle,
    tblposts.PostImage,
    tblcategory.CategoryName AS category,
    tblcategory.id AS cid,
    tblsubcategory.Subcategory AS subcategory,
    tblposts.PostDetails AS postdetails,
    tblposts.PostingDate AS postingdate,
    tblposts.PostUrl AS url
    FROM tblposts
        LEFT JOIN tblcategory ON tblcategory.id=tblposts.CategoryId
        LEFT JOIN tblsubcategory ON tblsubcategory.SubCategoryId=tblposts.SubCategoryId
    ORDER BY tblposts.id DESC LIMIT $offset, $no_of_records_per_page");
```

And my tblposts table is as follows:

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: you can  add a simple where to your request `where status != 0`

Comment: If you are only going to access result set data using column names, only make an assoc result set.

Comment: Could you please add the errors you get? Also the table structure could be useful

Comment: getting this type of error Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\newsportal\index.php on line 58

Comment: There is no code given that triggers that kind of error - please add more context. Additionally, are there any errors reported through `mysqli_error`?

Comment: What do you mean by inactive posts?, Have you added any columns to differentiate between active and inactive posts in DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are having problem with SQL queries as your question is likely relate to fetching data from data base. Based on the queries and screenshot of table you have provided, following will code will filter post from `is_active` column.

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT
    tblposts.id AS pid,
    tblposts.PostTitle AS posttitle,
    tblposts.PostImage,
    tblcategory.CategoryName AS category,
    tblcategory.id AS cid,
    tblsubcategory.Subcategory AS subcategory,
    tblposts.PostDetails AS postdetails,
    tblposts.PostingDate AS postingdate,
    tblposts.PostUrl AS url
    FROM tblposts
        LEFT JOIN tblcategory ON tblcategory.id=tblposts.CategoryId
        LEFT JOIN tblsubcategory ON tblsubcategory.SubCategoryId=tblposts.SubCategoryId
    WHERE tblposts.is_active = 0
    ORDER BY tblposts.id DESC LIMIT $offset, $no_of_records_per_page");
```

In the above code `WHERE tblposts.is_active = 0` will filter the post whose value on  `is_active` column is 0.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get what you really asked for, but based on your question...

You can add "where" condition on your sql.

eg: `SELECT .... FROM tbl_name WHERE tbl_name.status != '0';`